# Unable to understand the execution flow of the multithreading code

Tags: java, multithreading

I found this kind of code in my app and I am getting different outputs at different times. I am confused. Please tell me the possible execution flow of the code. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Vector;

class Producer extends Thread {

 static final int MAXQUEUE = 5;
 private Vector messages = new Vector();

 @Override
 public void run() {
     try {
         while (true) {
            putMessage();
            //sleep(5000);
         }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     }
 }

 private synchronized void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {
     while (messages.size() == MAXQUEUE) {
        wait();
     }
     messages.addElement(new java.util.Date().toString());
     System.out.println("put message");
     notify();
     //Later, when the necessary event happens, the thread that is     running it calls notify() from a block synchronized on the same object.
 }

 // Called by Consumer
 public synchronized String getMessage() throws InterruptedException {
     notify();
     while (messages.size() == 0) {
         wait();//By executing wait() from a synchronized block, a thread  gives up its hold on the lock and goes to sleep.
     }
     String message = (String) messages.firstElement();
     messages.removeElement(message);
     return message;
  }
 }



class Consumer extends Thread {

 Producer producer;

 Consumer(Producer p) {
    producer = p;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
     try {
         while (true) {
            String message = producer.getMessage();
            System.out.println("Got message: " + message);
            //sleep(200);
         }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Producer producer = new Producer();
    producer.start();
    new Consumer(producer).start();
 }
}
```

Please tell the possible flow of exection in few steps. Thanks so much.

Comment: What outputs are you getting?

Comment: Thread scheduling is unpredictable, therefore you get different outputs at different times. What exactly is surprising to you? Can you give an example of a result that you did not expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to "current date or time", it means "randomness". The reason of the different output of your code is not multi threads, but the

```
new java.util.Date()
```

Thread switching can cause randomness also, but it is very easy to avoid because of the existence of locks. Your code also has lock by using JAVA keyword "synchronized" on methods. When a method has a "synchronized", that equals you are using

```
synchronized(this) {...}
```

Which means different threads can not run into the same Producer object's {...} at the same time. The producer calls notify() after putting one ele to vector, which means producer says "The vector is not empty, please fetch something from it" to consumer. The consumer calls notify() after getting one ele from vector, which means consumer says "The vector is not full, please put your ele into it" to producer.

To know these things clearly, please learning the basics of locks and conditions in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Executing multiple threads will likely give you different output for the same input for repeated execution. This code is having a producer "produce" messages as long as the amount of messages produced do not exceed a max queue size and the consumer is "consuming" messages by printing them out and removing them from the queue as long as the queue isnt empty.

The producer-consumer problem is very popular and important to understanding how threads work with eachother synchronously. Check out this article for further explanation: http://ankitsambyal.blogspot.com/2014/02/mutex-in-java-explained-using-producer.html

Hope this helps!